# How to index select keys in Postgres jsonb data?

Tags: postgresql

I use jsonb type in Postgres for storing key-value documents. And I use GIN indexes on top of these documents for fast look-ups. All of it works well, although GIN indexes by default tend to be verbose, i.e. they index every key in the jsonb structure. I'd like to have more selective indexing.

Is it possible to do these with GIN indexes?

1. Have GIN only index the top-level keys, and leave the nested structures unindexed? OR
2. Have GIN only index specific keywords (I'm aware that I could create separate btree indexes for each keyword that needs to be indexed. I'm interested in knowing if I can get it done via GIN)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using auxiliary function that takes a JSONB document as input and array of keys and returns a new document with keys filtered, that you can then index with GIN:

```
create function jsonb_filter(doc jsonb, variadic keys text[]) 
returns jsonb
as 'select jsonb_object_agg(key, doc->key) from unnest(keys) key'
language sql
immutable;

create index filtered_index on jsonb_table 
using gin (jsonb_filter(data, 'a', 'b'));

select data->'a'
from jsonb_table
where jsonb_filter(data, 'a', 'b') @> '{"a":1}';
```

You may want to hardcode the set of keys you want to filter inside the function to avoid repeating them in queries.

If you want to just index the *presence* of some keys, then:

```
create function jsonb_keys(doc jsonb) 
returns text[]
as 'select array_agg(key) from jsonb_object_keys(doc) key'
language sql
immutable;

create index keys_index on jsonb_table 
using gin (jsonb_keys(data));

select data->'b'
FROM jsonb_table
where jsonb_keys(data) @> ARRAY['a'];
```

The function `jsonb_keys` can be modified to include only the keys you want to index.

Here is the relevant SqlFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b7935/6

Comment: add more data to the fiddle? so it would start using yoiur indexes? otherwise demonstrations does not work :)

Comment: @VaoTsun valid point, but the key to making indexes eligible is to have the _indexed expression_ in query filters :)